# Rails preview article

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing

I want create article preview. I need help.

```
string = '<p>Lorem ipsum</p> <hr> <p>Ipsum Lorem</p>'
```

1. How do I get the text before `<hr>` for preview of article.
2. How i can remove `<hr>` from string for full article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. How do I get the text before `<hr>` for preview of article.

Answer :--

```
irb(main):018:0> string.split(/<hr>/)
=> ["<p>Lorem ipsum</p> ", " <p>Ipsum Lorem</p>"]
irb(main):019:0> string.split(/<hr>/).first
=> "<p>Lorem ipsum</p> "
```

2.How i can remove `"<hr>"` from string for full article.

Answer:--

```
 irb(main):027:0> string = '<p>Lorem ipsum</p> <hr> <p>Ipsum Lorem</p>'
 => "<p>Lorem ipsum</p> <hr> <p>Ipsum Lorem</p>"
 irb(main):028:0> string.gsub("<hr>", "")
 => "<p>Lorem ipsum</p>  <p>Ipsum Lorem</p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`delete` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-delete) on the string:

```
string = '<p>Lorem ipsum</p> <hr> <p>Ipsum Lorem</p>'
string.delete!("<hr>")
```